# grouping with colorbox doesn't seem to work properly

Tags: jquery, image, drupal, colorbox, grouping

I'm working with Drupal 7 and am attempting to create a gallery using colorbox. I have set the 
**rel** argument of my images to the same value but grouping doesn't seem to be working...
My gallery is located at: http://quaaoutlodge.com/gallery and any help or assistance would be appreciated!

Thank you!
Ron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Colorbox is grouping upon the class name not the rel attribute like lightbox2 does.